# How to tidy data that is one long string of numbers

Tags: r, dataset, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

I'm still very new to data science and R, but my work requires me to work through some very large, very messy data sets with little to no structure to them. I'm currently working with a US Freight text file (Approximately 48,000 characters, 13,341 rows, and 1 column) containing information such as FIPS Codes, Weigh Station Identification Numbers, Truck Weights, etc, and the data is formatted in the following way:

[image]

The spacing is not acting as the delimiter, nothing really is.

> **S02000101**11171R1T13 00 13 00 2PLP001700000000 8196762351650150252360          9100170Y170000008007Y3000000030        PARKS HIGHWAY AT CHULITNA - NB

And to further explain the data itself, the characters are coded to identify specific things such as the S indicating the record type, 02 being the FIPS code for Alaska,000101 being the Station Identification code.

I don't really know where to take this dataset and clean it up by adding new columns to separate the record type, FIPS Code, Station Identification Code, etc. Suggestions?

**Column numbers Identify the location of each record in every piece of station data.**
[image]

Comment: You can use regular expressions to split the strings into something workable, but unless you lay out the whole heuristic for how to do so we can't do much. E.g. do you know that a leading character should be one of several record types, the FIPS is always the next two characters, the station code is 6 numbers long etc... It's also not clear if you have one long string or many strings

Comment: It looks like the data could possibly be in a fixed width format? In that case, things like `readr::read_fwf` could be useful

Comment: @CalumYou Yes, my apologies. I'll edit the post and add the leading characters information for clarification.

Comment: @TheIllusiveNick yes, this definitely looks like a fixed-width format now. You basically just need to take those widths and plug them into `read_fwf` to get the data read in nicely.

Comment: @Marius I am running into to problem when using read_fwf, though. It's producing an "Error: `file` must be a string, raw vector or a connection." when creating an argument with start and end width positions. >read_fwf(`AK_APR_2017.(TMAS)`, fwf_cols(record_type = 1, FIPS = c(2,3))) ... is a snippet of my code; any ideas as to why I may be running into this problem?

Comment: You should be reading in the data from the original file with read_fwf, so the first argument should be the filename, as a string. It looks like you've already read in the data and are feeding it to read_fwf.